# How to use a CASE statement with a JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use join statement that vary based on certain case statements. When the field lane.dest_postal_code_prefix is NOT NULL then I want the join to be like the first block of code below.
When the field lane.dest_postal_code_prefix is NULL then I want the join to be like second block of code below.
(Note the difference on the ON conditions between the two cases)

I need some help adding the case statement to the join clause.

```
--WHEN lane.dest_postal_code_prefix is NOT NULL
SELECT * FROM big_bucket_bridge A
    LEFT JOIN lane 
    ON
    (
    A.customer_country = lane.dest_country_code
    AND
    SUBSTRING( A.ddm_zip, 1, LENGTH( lane.dest_postal_code_prefix ) ) = 
    lane.dest_postal_code_prefix
        )

WHERE  
    snapshot_day between '2019-06-23'-22 and '2019-06-23'
    AND (is_before_cutoff_g OR (is_before_cutoff_opt_g and not under_two))
    AND row_n =1
;

--WHEN lane.dest_postal_code_prefix is NULL
SELECT * FROM big_bucket_bridge A
    LEFT JOIN lane 
    ON
    (
    A.customer_country = lane.dest_country_code
    )

WHERE  
    snapshot_day between '2019-06-23'-22 and '2019-06-23'
    AND (is_before_cutoff_g OR (is_before_cutoff_opt_g and not under_two))
    AND row_n =1
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one ON clause like this:

```
ON
(
A.customer_country = lane.dest_country_code
AND
COALESCE(SUBSTRING(A.ddm_zip, 1, LENGTH( lane.dest_postal_code_prefix )), '') = CASE 
  WHEN lane.dest_postal_code_prefix IS NOT NULL THEN lane.dest_postal_code_prefix 
  ELSE COALESCE(SUBSTRING(A.ddm_zip, 1, LENGTH( lane.dest_postal_code_prefix )), '')
END
)
```

In the 2nd case (else part) the condition is always true because it is:

```
COALESCE(SUBSTRING(A.ddm_zip, 1, LENGTH( lane.dest_postal_code_prefix )), '') = COALESCE(SUBSTRING(A.ddm_zip, 1, LENGTH( lane.dest_postal_code_prefix )), '')
```

so the only actual condition is

```
A.customer_country = lane.dest_country_code
```

Comment: this part of the ON clause is not there in your answer A.ead_2g_route_id = lane.route_id ......this part should be present WHEN lane.dest_postal_code_prefix is NOT NULL so I am a bit confused ?

Comment: ok thanks for the edits, I tried using this method and I get a syntax error of ")" . Not quite sure why though as all my brackets should be correct. i have updated the question with the updated field I am using in my join clause where the error is happening

Comment: I think you need to remove the double parentheses:... =    lane.dest_postal_code_prefix))

Comment: just tried that and still the same error SUBSTRING( A.ddm_zip, 1, LENGTH( lane.dest_postal_code_prefix ) ) = CASE WHEN lane.dest_postal_code_prefix IS NOT NULL
 THEN lane.dest_postal_code_prefix ELSE SUBSTRING( A.ddm_zip, 1, LENGTH( lane.dest_postal_code_prefix ) )

Comment: Is this Oracle? There is no SUBSTRING function in Oracle. Use SUBSTR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195592/discussion-between-bp123-and-forpas).